# C# Ascii Converter Not working Properly and Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, arrays, ascii, converters, subroutine

I am fairly new to programming so I'm sorry if there's a really simple fix it this but i couldn't find a solution.

I have created this sub-routine which goes through the names array which is a string and converts each name to ascii and saves it to the asciiname double array, the reason it is a double array is because it wasn't working when i was using a int because it gave me an error saying that value was either to big or too small.

```
    private static void AsciiCoverter(string[] names,double [] AsciiNames)
    {
        double temp = 0;
        double SingleVal = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            string s = names[i];
            string egg = " " ;
            foreach (char c in s)
            {
                SingleVal = (Convert.ToInt64(c));
                egg = egg + SingleVal;
            }
            temp = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToInt64(temp.ToString() + egg));
            AsciiNames[i] = temp;
            temp = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you, please, provide some examples of the input and corresponding desired output?

Comment: you're trying to convert `egg` (please, don't give such "funny" names to your variables), to `Int64`. But, depending on your names array length, that number can be too large to convert to `int64`. If you have just one name, let's say "Christopher", `ascii` values will be bigger than `int64`

Comment: please don't use `temp` like that at the very least declare it inside the `for` loop so you don't have to reset it each time. Also what result are you expecting from trying to convert a string like `"0 68"` to a number?

Comment: I've no idea what you are trying to achieve with that code, but have you checked out the System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string) method? See here for an example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I got you! It's all about the `egg`, right. ^^